# Can python threads send status back to the main

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python 3 program that creates a series of 10 threads and they do a variety of work on their own. Is there a way to have those threads send a status back to the main thread?

I know that from main I can call `is_alive()` and get a "hearbeat" but I'm looking for more than just a boolean. Is there a way for me to collect a series of values from my thread at any given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of ways to do that. One is a simple shared variable guarded by [a mutex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#lock-objects). For that you'd do something like:

```
def function_called_in_thread(shared_variable, shared_lock):
   # do stuff
   with shared_lock:
       # e.g. if it's an integer and it's a heartbeat count
       shared_variable += 1
       # e.g. if it's a list
       shared_variable.append(some_result)
```

Then in the main thread you'd do something like:

```
# assuming it's an integer
shared_variable = 0
lock = threading.Lock()
thread = Thread(target=function_called_in_thread, args=(shared_variable, lock))
thread.start()
# A loop to check on the status of the thread via the shared variable
while True:
    with lock:
      print('The value of the shared variable is:', shared_variable)
    time.sleep(10)
```

There's also some purpose built data structures designed for sharing information between threads including [queues](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#module-queue). Additional objects like [semaphores](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects), [condition variables](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#condition-objects), and [barriers](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) let threads coordinate so they can, for example, wait until another thread has reached some goal.

Comment: Great answer. Ironically, I didn't use your code. But you mentioned the Queues object and that's exactly what I was looking for to talk back and forth. Thanks!